# IF statement in conditional fromating that involves date +10 days

Tags: excel

I need a conditional formatting If formula that reads like this. If the return date is 10 days or more from the out date then red. Mine looks like this:
=IF(I2>H2=10) format red. I know this is simple but I cannot seem to figure out what I'm missing here. Please help.

Comment: `=I2>=H2+10` the if is not needed

Comment: I apologize, that was a typo, that is what I have =IF(I2>H2+10)

Comment: I edited the comment.  The IF is not needed.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you, I feel so dumb. Have a wonderful day!